# Django check and alternate Docker Compose file: Debug flag not being set?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to prep a Django application for production. I created an alternate docker-compose YML file where I specify DEBUG=0. However when I run the django check for deployment, it says that DEBUG is set to True.

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong? I thought it was an issue with my use of Docker. But is it perhaps an issue with how I'm using Django?

**Here are my steps:**

1. Created my project with docker-compose.yml (see below)
2. Created docker-compose-prod.yml for production (see below)
3. Ran the following

```
$ docker-compose down
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml up -d --build
$ docker-compose exec web python manage.py check --deploy
```

4. Output of the check: 
   `?: (security.W018) You should not have DEBUG set to True in deployment.`

**Some of investigatory steps so far:**

A. Check the environment variables.

```
$ docker-compose exec web python
>>> import os
>>> os.environ.get('DEBUG')
'0'
```

B. Try rebuilding docker image in different ways, e.g. with --no-cache flag

C. Set the DEBUG flag in settings.py in a conditional code block (rather than using os.environ.get). This seemed to work. But I don't understand why? Code detail below.

**Code excerpts**

1. Excerpt from docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  web:
    ...
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=development
      - SECRET_KEY=randomlongseriesofchars
      - DEBUG=1
```

2. Excerpt from docker-compose-prod.yml

```
services:
  web:
    ...
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=production
      - SECRET_KEY=anotherrandomlongseriesofchars
      - DEBUG=0
```

3. Excerpts from settings.py

```
ENVIRONMENT = os.environ.get('ENVIRONMENT', default='production') 
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', default=0)  #How is DEBUG being set to True?
...
if ENVIRONMENT == 'production':
    [Various settings for production]
    [Putting DEBUG=0 in this conditional block works]
```

Comment: Please set it to `False`, *not* `0`.

Comment: @oleg-russkin is the answer, so I solved this putting `DEBUG=True` and with
`DEBUG = (os.getenv('DEBUG', False) == 'True')` maybe others with the same issue get it useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Environment variables are strings**, so result of `os.environ.get()` is a string.

If code expects variable to be int, boolean, etc - not string - first, it might fail. Or, try converting to desired type, an that might differ from desired result.

I.e., if converting to boolean, only empty string would result in `False`.

So, possible options are:

- add logic to first read env vars and then correctly convert or parse them into target arguments.
- use env helpers, like [django-environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ), [environs](https://github.com/sloria/environs) which allow to auto-convert env vars to taget type and provide useful utility methods, generally providing something you might have implemented yourself in option 1
- use different schema to pass arguments - i.e. not by env vars, but by custom settings file (there also exist helpers for that). Someone prefers env vars, someone prefers files, it also might depend on project / team / how you deploy (what is supported by instrument).

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't considered types! Also thanks for pointing me towards some env helpers. I may implement those in the future. For now, I just used this bit of code to replace my DEBUG line in settings.py: `if os.environ.get('DEBUG', default=0).lower() in ['true','1']:
    DEBUG = True
else:
    DEBUG = False`

Answer (score 0):

```
DEBUG = (os.getenv('DEBUG', '0') == '1')
```